# Which warrior can be considered the reason for the death of Bhishma?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, bhishma, shikhandi

Bhishma died on the bed of arrows after several days of completion of the MahAbhArata war.
Among Arjuna & Shikhandi, who can be considered the "slayer of Bhishma" or the reason of Bhishma getting killed ultimately?

Comment: Shikhandi is the rebirth of the girl whom Bhishma bring from swaymwar. She said to Bhishma that he has to marry him now but he refused coz of his promise. He even fought Parshurama but didn't leave his promise. Then she start seeking revenge from Bhishma and got boon from Shiva that she will be reason of Bhishma's death in her next birth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Shikhandi**.

> Dhritarashtra said,--'How hath Bhishma, that bull among the Kurus, been slain by Sikhandin? [[Bhishma Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06014.htm) found in [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17300/1049)]
>
> When that lord of the world, the valiant Bhishma, having encountered Shikhandi, met with his death like a lion meeting with his at the hands of a jackal, what can it be but destiny?  [[Shalya Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m09/m09002.htm)
>
> Then the slayer of Bhishma, the mighty Shikhandi, with all the Prabhadrakas, assailed the hero from every side with diverse kinds of weapons.  [[Sauptika Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10008.htm)

Moreover, it seems less likely that, Arjuna being devoted to Drona & Bhishma would have 'killed' them. This was evident during the discourse of Gita's 1st chapter. Since Bhishma didn't want to kill any of the PAndava, possibly Arjuna might have reciprocated the same.

---

As mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17267/1049), Bhishma indeed would have informed about the way he can be killed to PAndava-s. However, ultimately Shikhandi would have pierced the majority of the arrows to Bhishma's body with some unspecified help from Arjuna as mentioned below (which interprets Arjuna as the slayer).

> Viewing his relationship of grandsire unto them, the sons of Pandu, O sire, were spared in dreadful battle by Bhishma for ten successive days! Thyself also having laid aside thy weapons, the valiant Bhishma was slain in great battle by Phalguni with Shikhandi before him!  [[Karna Parva]](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08010.htm)

Comment: BHishma has iccha mrityu boon. Who can slay him?

Comment: shikandi is a napunsak in my words. tucha daridra napunsak

Answer (score 3):

Arjuna.

Ganga was sad that Bhishma was slain by Shikandhi.

> Ye sinless ones, listen to me as I say unto you all that occurred
> (with respect to my son). Possessed of royal conduct and disposition,
> and endued with wisdom and high birth, my son was the
> benefactor of all the seniors of his race. He was devoted to his
> sire and was of high vows. He could not be vanquished by even Rama of Jamadagni's race with his celestial weapons of great energy. **Alas, that hero has been slain by Sikhandin.** Ye kings, without doubt, my heart is made of adamant, for it does not break even at the disappearance of that son from my sight! At the Self choice at Kasi, he vanquished on a single car the assembled Kshatriyas and ravished the three princesses (for his step-brother Vichitravirya)! **There was no one on earth that equalled him in might. Alas, my heart does not break upon hearing the slaughter of that son of mine by Sikhandin!'**

Krishna then explained that it was not Shikandi but Arjuna that slew Bhishma.

> Krishna said, **'O amiable one, be comforted. Do not yield to grief, O thou of beautiful features!** Without doubt, thy son has gone to the highest region of felicity! He was one of the Vasus of great energy. Through a curse, O thou of beautiful features, he had to take birth among men. It behoveth thee not to grieve for him. Agreeably to Kshatriya duties, **he was slain by Dhananjaya on the field of battle while engaged in battle. He has not been slain, O goddess, by Sikhandin.** The very chief of the celestials himself could not slay Bhishma in battle when he stood with stretched bow in hand.

---

When Bhishma battled Parashurama, his ancestors told him that Arjuna is destined to be the slayer of Bhishma.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05188.htm

> **Study (of the Vedas) and practice of vows are the highest wealth of
> Brahmanas!** For some reason, before 'this, thou hadst been ordered by
> us to take up weapons. Thou hadst then perpetrated that terrible and
> unbecoming feat. Let this battle with Bhishma be thy very last, for
> enough of it thou hadst already.
>
> O thou of mighty arms, leave the combat. Blessed be thou, ***let this be
> the very last instance of thy taking up the bow!*** O invincible one,
> throw thy bow aside, and practice ascetic austerities
>
> That foremost of the Pandavas, ***Arjuna***, the mighty son of Indra, hath
> been **ordained by the Self-create to be the slayer of Bhishma**!'

---

Arjuna was also cursed by the Vasus because he was the one who slayed Bhishma.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14081.htm

> After the fall of Santanu's son, those deities, viz., the Vasus, coming to the banks of Ganga, bathed in her waters, and calling the goddess of that stream, they uttered these terrible words having the sanction of Bhagirathi herself, viz.,--**Santanu's son Bhishma has been slain by Dhananjaya.** Verily, O goddess, Bhishma then was engaged with another, and had ceased to fight. **For this fault we shall today denounce a curse on Dhananjaya.--To this, the goddess Ganga readily assented, saying,--Be it so!**