# How many times Krishna called Arjuna with different names? And what are those names?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

I am curious to know that in Bhagavad Gita, what were the names used by Krishna to call Arjuna to boost him?

Comment: "How many times" b'cz of this, question might get close as too broad I guess.

Comment: I think there's a related question to this of different names with Arjuna. Will try to find!

Comment: @krishna I need number if all names are not available.

Comment: Closely related: [Various appellations of Arjuna and their significance](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15328/277)

Comment: This isn't all from Bhagavad Gita, Though thanks for sharing this, appreciated.